# C# Graphics causes OutOfMemory

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm trying to work with Graphics and Images in C#. I made a zoom function. But after calling the zoom funcion several times I get an OutOfMemory error. I see the memory usage increase at every call to my Zoom function. I do not understand why this is happening.

```
Image Zoom(Image img, Point ZoomLvl)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, (img.Width * ZoomLvl.X / 100), (img.Height * ZoomLvl.Y / 100));
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        return bmp;
    }
```

Which is called like this:

```
imgDisplayed = Zoom(imgOriginal, new Point(ZoomLevel, ZoomLevel));
picImage.Image = imgDisplayed;
```

imgOriginal is an Image object that contains my original image. imgDisplayed is also an Image object that the zoomed image is loaded into. Both these image objects have a global scope inside my class.
picImage is a picturebox on my form showing the zoomed image.

Im currently working with 8k images and OutOfMemory occurs after about 20 - 30 times. It happens on the first line of code in the zoom function where a new bitmap obkect is created. Memory usage is at 4G by then.

I do not see a reason for my memory usage to grow. But it does. So I am not understanding something here.

Comment: You need to call .Dispose() on the bitmap when it's finished with it to free up unmanaged resources.

Comment: *Everything* which implements `IDisposable`  (has a `Dispose` method). must be disposed if you create it. Further zooming in and out of the same image will cause the quality to degrade.  Better to adjust the zoom factor over and over on *the same* original image

Comment: How can I Dispose it when it is directly assigned to imgDisplayed on return of the function call? I do see your point, but I just dont see how.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Dispose either bitmap (in some time) or original image passed to Zoom method after creating new bitmap. These objects are stored in process memory and never freed until process exit or you call Dispose.

Additionally, this code fragment does nothing in the way that was used.

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
```

If you want to affect the quality of the image reduction operation then don't use the Bitmap constructor, use the DrawImage method from Graphics object.

Graphics object should also be disposed e.g. by closing it in using statement.

Comment: That makes sense. However I am not totaly understanding it yet. As a C-guy I am thinking in terms of stack, passing by value and reference. To me it seems that objects getting out of scope are not removed from memory. It's very important to understand when I need to do that manually. Else memory problems keep appearing in my work.

Comment: I already was wondering about that section with the graphics object. It came straight from a tutorial that I followed. I was surpriced if it working and commenting out does not change a thing. Even the OutOfMemory remains.

Comment: Use ILSpy or other similar tool to look inside classes. You will know how they works internally.